# when generating notification on android 11 then notification content format is different and on android 13 notification content format is different

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

When we generate notification in our app using firebase, android 11 notification content has different data and android 13 notification content different data.

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  Map<String, String> body = Collections.emptyMap();

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        body = remoteMessage.getData();
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + body);
        //messageBody = body.toString();
    }

  sendNotification(body);
}


private void sendNotification(Map<String, String> messageBody) {
    Intent intent = null;

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        createChannel(notificationManager);
    }


   String notificationType = messageBody.get("notificationType");
    String typeOfPatient = messageBody.get("");

    if ((notificationType != null ) && (notificationType.equalsIgnoreCase("chatmessage"))){
        intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("notify", true);
    }


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0  /*Request code*/ , intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    String title = "Patient Name " + messageBody.get("name");
    String message;
    /*if (messageBody.get("notificationType").equalsIgnoreCase("episode"))
        message = messageBody.get("message");
    else
        message = "Lab Date is " + messageBody.get("labDate");*/


     NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,getResources().getString(R.string.notification_channel))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_doctor_logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentInfo("message")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
    bigTextStyle.bigText("message");

    notificationBuilder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());


}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void createChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
    String name = getResources().getString(R.string.notification_channel);
    String description = getResources().getString(R.string.description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(name, name, importance);
    mChannel.setDescription(description);
    mChannel.enableLights(true);
    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}
```

[image]

[image]